# SQL Report Builder 3.0 - Drop down list doesn't populate on some computers

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm inclined to think this is a permission-based issue, but I've ensured permissions match as best as I can, so I'm really needing some tips on what other things I can check.

There is nothing wrong with the query or the report itself, as most computers can open it in SSRS, select whatever they want and run the report. I've even manually run the query used to populate the list and I get results. On my machine, for example, the drop down list is blank. Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: Output the Built-in UserId field in the report footer and run it on one computer that's working and another that's not working.  See if they are different.  Hopefully they are and you can troubleshoot from there.  There's also the ReportServerURL field if that's relevant to your setup.

Comment: If you edit the report in Report Builder, does it populate the drop down list? Is everyone using the same browser/version?

Comment: Even in Report Builder, I still get no drop-down results. Yes, all using IE. Not certain versions are all exact same, but I imagine they are.

Comment: pwilcox - I can't run the report on a machine that the list doesn't populate. It requires a value from the list before I can run it. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I figured it out. I looked at another report where I had a list and compared the queries. In the report where it wasn't working, the query to populate the drop down was dependent on the existence of my network credentials in another table. Thanks for your tips regardless guys!